# Get title of page containing post grid within the posts

Tags: php, loop, shortcode

I have a page containing a post grid. Within the text of these posts I want to use a shortcode to display the title of the page containing this grid. So, when my page title is "test" I want to be able to display "test" within the content of my post text in the post grid.
I made this simple shortcode

```
function page_title_sc( ){
   return get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode( 'paginatitel', 'page_title_sc' );
```

but this code displays the title of the post in my grid, not the title of the page containing this grid. Is there a way to change this shortcode so it can display the page title instead of the post title?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/381777/edit) to show us more of the code in question. How are you creating your "post grid"?

Comment: I'm creating the post grid with the bakery builder Post Grid building block. Am I correct that I can only do this by custom coding? I suppose the post grid building block starts a new loop for the posts so get_the_title will display the title of the post? I'm using the Post grid block because I want to show random posts in a certain category.  I can make some custom code to (1) get the ID's of the random posts (WP_Query), reset the post data (wp_reset_postdata() and then displaying the posts  by ID (without stating a new loop). But is this the only way to do this?

Comment: You will have to ask the plugin or theme developers / support any questions about how to use their product.